# In Android 10, how to do post processing of video buffer without touching framework or OpenMAX components

Tags: android, video, decode

I have to do some post processing on decoded video buffers (every frame) before sending it to Surface Flinger for rendering. After project treble, since I cannot modify the framework and I cannot modify vendor provided OpenMAX layers, how can I add my post processing? Can somebody point to a similar implementation or any design pointers would be helpful

Comment: Hi Palpal, good effort in the question asked by you but it seems that the question still lacks the codes which you have used...

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this would be to use OpenCV which will allow you process each frame before it is displayed.

For example, the call back method 'onCameraFrame' this gives you access to the frame from the input source, in this case a camera, before you render it.

A couple of caveats:

- You have to make sure the processing you do fits within the time you have between each frame. If you have an issue with this, one workaround, which may work depending on your use case, can be to do the heavy processing every nth frame and use the same result for any frames in between.
- OpenCV for Android documentation is still Eclispe based. If you want to work with Android Studio, then you will need to do some online reading and searching for guides and tips and issue workarounds. There are more of these available now so it seems better than it was in the past.

A good simple example to look at first is the color club detection which detects an object or blob of a specific color each frame: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/color-blob-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/colorblobdetect

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Like you mentioned, this could work for camera capture use cases. My problem is specific to decoded video data, for which I couldn't find a similar API which gives me the decoded buffer.